# Rails Service Object, adding errors to new Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I recently had a rails model that had several callbacks on it like so:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :fetch_posts
  after_create :build_posts

  def fetch_posts
    fetch_collection
  rescue MyException => e
    self.errors.add(:post, e.message)
  end

  def build_posts
    fetch_collection.each do |item|
      DifferentModel.build(item)
    end
  end

  def fetch_collection
    @collection ||= method_that_fetches_collection_from_external_source
  end
end
```

This was working just fine but it was making it extremely difficult to write tests, as whenever I wanted to create a `Model` I had to stub out all the callbacks.  Enter service objects:

```
class ModelFetcher

  attr_reader :model

  def initialize(model)
    @model = model
  end

   def save
     model.fetch_posts
     if model.save
       model.build_posts
       return true
     else
       return false
     end
  end
end
```

The problem I'm seeing now, in the case where a model does indeed contain an error (from the fetch posts method), it doesn't get carried over to the `model.save` call in the SO. That is to say, the `Model.new` has an error, but once I call `.save` on that `Model.new` it doesn't maintain the error and the model saves properly.

I considered adding `validate :fetch_posts` but then I am back in the same situation I was before as this is essentially a callback.

Any advice on how to structure this better? Is it possible to maintain an error from `Model.new` to `.save`? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Comment: what are your validations? Not sure I completely understand the scenario.

Comment: @engineersmnky No validations per se, if I get an error from my external call I just throw an exception, and the :fetch_posts method in the :before_validate callback just adds an error to the model, so it can't save. That's the closest thing to a validation.

Comment: okay so the issue here is that you are using `fetch_posts` which will generate the error but then when you save it will clear the errors as well as run `fetch_posts` again which will not fail this time because it is simply recalling `@collection` which won't fail. Why are you calling `fetch_posts` prior to `save` when `save` calls it through the `before_validation`? You could try `model.fetch_posts` and then `model.errors.any?` instead of `save`

Comment: @engineersmnky that makes sense. In the service object example I have removed the callbacks, so that `before_validation` doesn't get run. But I will mess around with `model.errors.any?` and see if I can get it to work that way.

Comment: Yeah the issue is that `save` is not running any validations so it will always be true so you will need to check through another method to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @engineersmnky I ended up fixing it with the first `model.errors.any?` method you described. If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Added this as an addition to my answer as I think that my other suggestion holds merit in your exact use care as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution which is to overwrite `run_validations!` since you have none.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :build_posts

  def fetch_posts
    fetch_collection
    rescue MyException => e
      self.errors.add(:post, e.message)
  end

  def build_posts
    fetch_collection.each do |item|
      DifferentModel.build(item)
    end
  end

  def fetch_collection
    @collection ||= method_that_fetches_collection_from_external_source
  end
private
  def run_validations!
    fetch_posts
    errors.empty?
  end
end
```

Usually this method looks like

```
def run_validations! 
  run_callbacks :validate
  errors.empty?
end
```

but since you have no validations it should serve a similar purpose on `#save`.

Or as I suggested in a comment you can replace `save` with `model.errors.any?` Since `save` will clear your original errors set by `fetch_posts` but `errors.any?` Will check if there were errors during the `fecth_posts` method.